# Making sure my Textbox and ComboBox have selected values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'd like to be able to chose a desired number of repetitions (combobox dropdown menu) in a excercise, and let the user input the used weight (textbox) and calculate a maximum weight for that excercise.

[image]

**So my problem is**; when I select a desired number from my combobox it is as like its not "chosen" when I'm debugging, if that makes sense. I quite frankly don't know where in all of this I'd be making the actual "calculator"?

So I've made a few classes and a view:

### RepMaxCalcDataStorage

```
public class RepMaxCalcDataStorage : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _repRange;
    private double _weightUsed;

    public int CalculateRepRange 
    { 
        get { return _repRange; } 
        set { value = _repRange; } 
    }

    public double CalculateWeightUsed 
    { 
        get { return _weightUsed; } 
        set { value = _weightUsed; } 
    }
}
```

### ViewModelBase

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
        new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

### OneRepMaxCalcViewModel

```
public class OneRepMaxCalcViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<double> _repRange;
    private RepMaxCalcDataStorage _dataStorage;
    private int _ItemIsSeleceted;

    public OneRepMaxCalcViewModel ()
    {
        _repRange = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };
        _dataStorage = new RepMaxCalcDataStorage();
    }

    public List<double> GetRepRange { get { return _repRange; } set { value = _repRange; } }
    public RepMaxCalcDataStorage DataStorage { get { return _dataStorage; } set { value = _dataStorage; } }
    public int SelectedRep { get { return _ItemIsSeleceted;  }
        set
        {
            value = _dataStorage.CalculateRepRange ;
            if(_ItemIsSeleceted != 0)
            {
                _dataStorage.CalculateRepRange = _ItemIsSeleceted;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RepMaxCalcDataStorage));
        }
    }

    public double WeightUsed 
    { 
        get { return _dataStorage.CalculateWeightUsed; } 
        set { value = _dataStorage.CalculateWeightUsed; } 
    }
}
```

### RepMaxCalculator

```
public class _1RepMaxCalcViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<double> _repRange;
    private double _weightLifted;
    private double _calculatedResults;
    private RepMaxCalcDataStorage _dataStorage;

    public _1RepMaxCalcViewModel(double CalculatedResults, double WeightLifted)
    {
        _repRange = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };
        _weightLifted = WeightLifted;
        _calculatedResults = CalculatedResults;
        _dataStorage = new RepMaxCalcDataStorage();
    }

    public List<double> GetRepRange 
    { 
        get { return _repRange; } 
        set { value = _repRange; } 
    }

    public RepMaxCalcDataStorage DataStorage 
    { 
        get { return _dataStorage; } 
        set { value = _dataStorage; } 
    }

    public double Calculate1RepMax 
    { 
        get { return _calculatedResults; } 
    }

    public double TotalWeightLifted 
    { 
        get { return _weightLifted; } 
        set { value = _weightLifted; } 
    }
}
```

### 1RepMaxCalculatorPage

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="543,313,463,588">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="White" Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select Rep Range:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22"/>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="DimGray" ItemsSource="{Binding GetRepRange}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRep, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="180"  />
    </StackPanel>
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="724,313,1011,588">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="White" Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Weight used:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#e5e5e5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180"/>
    </StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="961,313,774,588">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="White" Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Your 1 Rep M:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#e5e5e5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

## SOLUTIONS:

What my classes and xaml looks like, now that I found my solution:

### RepMaxCalcDataStorage

```
  public class RepMaxCalcDataStorage : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _repRange;
    private double _weightUsed;

    public RepMaxCalcDataStorage()
    {

    }

    public int CalculateRepRange
    {
        get { return _repRange; }
        set { _repRange = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public double CalculateWeightUsed
    {
        get { return _weightUsed; }
        set { _weightUsed = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

}
```

### ViewModelBase

Same as before.

### OneRepMaxCalcViewModel

```
public class OneRepMaxCalcViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<double> _repRange;
    private RepMaxCalcDataStorage _dataStorage;
    private RelayCommand _relayCommand;
    private double _calculationResults;

    public OneRepMaxCalcViewModel ()
    {
        _repRange = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };
        _dataStorage = new RepMaxCalcDataStorage();
        _relayCommand = new RelayCommand(CalculateMax);
    }

    public List<double> GetRepRange
    {
        get { return _repRange; }
        set { _repRange = value; }
    }

    public RepMaxCalcDataStorage DataStorage
    {
        get { return _dataStorage; }
        set { _dataStorage = value ; }
    }

    public int SelectedRep
    {
        get { return _dataStorage.CalculateRepRange; }
        set
        {
            _dataStorage.CalculateRepRange = value ;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand GetCalculationResults
    {
        get { return _relayCommand; }
        set { _relayCommand = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public double GetResults
    {
        get { return _calculationResults; }
        set { _calculationResults = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public void CalculateMax()
    {
        _calculationResults = (DataStorage.CalculateWeightUsed * DataStorage.CalculateRepRange * 0.033) + DataStorage.CalculateWeightUsed;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GetResults));
    }
}
```

### RepMaxCalculator

Deleted as it was repeated code.

### 1RepMaxCalculatorPage

Combobox "Select Rep Range" bindings:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding GetRepRange}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRep, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

TextBox "Weight Used" bindings:

```
Text="{Binding DataStorage.CalculateWeightUsed, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Button "Calculate" bindings:

```
Command="{Binding GetCalculationResults}"
```

Textbox "Your 1 Rep M"

```
Text="{Binding GetResults}"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question so that the code is more readable. Please look at the edit so you can take that into account next time you ask a question

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks a lot, I'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the setters of your properties, you are putting

```
value = _repRange;
```

where _repRange is used as an example, as all of the setters shown here do the same.

This is backwards, you want the variable to receive the value.

```
_repRange = value;
```

also in the OneRepMaxCalcViewModel class, change the SelectedRep setter to something like this.

```
public int SelectedRep { get { return _ItemIsSelected;  }
    set
    {
        _dataStorage.CalculateRepRange = value;
        _ItemIsSelected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RepMaxCalcDataStorage));
    }
}
```

This makes it so that _ItemIsSelected is always updated to the currently selected item. Along with this, you will want either set the comboBox's selection to a valid value when the form is loaded, or initialize _ItemIsSelected to some value (such as Int32.MinValue) which indicates no selection. This is in case the user has not selected anything by the time the variable is used.

Comment: Hello thanks a lot for your answer, it makes sense. However, I'm not sure how'd go about making the if statement then, if you'd care to clarify I'd appreciate it

Comment: @KasperKofoed What is the intended purpose of the if statement? The value being sent to the setter is the item (in this case the numbers 1 through 20), rather than the index. So operating the comboBox in your example will never set '_ItemIsSeleceted' to 0 anyway. Is it meant to avoid having nothing selected?

Comment: Well when you put it like that, I assumed that I'd need to implement something to use when I make the code to calculate the maxrep. Like the combobox + textbox = "...."   

So I wouldn't actually have to implement  _ItemIsSelected?

Comment: @KasperKofoed If you intended for _ItemIsSelected to hold the currently selected item, then there's no need for the if statement at all. I've updated the end of my answer to make _ItemIsSelected always update to the currently selected item